# Creating a class Hierarchy for Atoms,neutrons,protons,chemical reationc

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c#-express-2010

I need help to create a program that can show the hierarchy of any  Atoms and its components (neutrons,protons,electrons,and chemical reaction)
Here is a code of what i have done so far,being a novice at the subject

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Atoms
{
    public class Atoms
    {
      protected string name = "Sodium";
          protected string element ="Metal";

        public virtual void GetInfo()
        {
         Console.WriteLine("name: {0}",name);
            Console.WriteLine("element: {0}", element);

        }
    }
    class Proton : Atoms
    {
        public int number = 11 ;
        public override void  GetInfo()
{
     base.GetInfo();
            Console.WriteLine("Proton number: {0}",number);

      }
}
    class Electron : Atoms
    {
        public int number = 11;
        public override void GetInfo()
        {
            base.GetInfo();
            Console.WriteLine("Electron number: {0}", number);
        }
        class Neutrons : Atoms
        {
            public int number = 12;
            public override void GetInfo()
            {
                base.GetInfo();
                Console.WriteLine("Neutron  number: {0}", number);
            }
            class TestClass
            {
                static void Main()
                {
                    Proton P = new Proton();
                    P.GetInfo();
                    Neutrons N = new Neutrons();
                    N.GetInfo();
                    Electron E = new Electron();
                    E.GetInfo();
                    Console.WriteLine("click any key to exit");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the question exactly?

Comment: Implement a class hierarchy nucleus of an atom, proton, neutron, electron, photon, atom, element, ion, and chemical reaction.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate more what you want to get out of it.  Also most of the community are not going to be physicists or chemists, so you might want to explain the hierarchy.

Comment: @SmartZulu it is not question, it is your homework statement. If you want to get some help here with your homework you have to do two things: 1) show what you have (tick) 2) ask clear **specific** question, not just do please my homework.

Comment: That being said, SO is more about solving specific problems in your code and not to help design your objects, so you might not get an answer that works right for you.

Answer (score 4):

*Caveat: Excuse my highschool understanding of sub-atomic physics, if ive got anything factually wrong im sure I'll explain the principle well enough*

What you're trying to model is a series of  `has a` relationships. ie

- An *Atom* **has** zero or more *Nutrons*
- An *Atom* **has** one or more *Electrons*
- An *Atom* **has** one or more *Protons*

Now, a *has a* relationship is not modelled using Inheritance as you've tried to do, it is modelled by Composition.

```
public class Atom
{
    private List<Neutron> neutrons;
    private List<Electron> electrons;
    private List<Proton> neutrons;
}
```

It may well be that each class `Neutron`, `Electron` and `Proton` have a common base class / interface which relates them back to the `Atom` they belong to:

```
public interface IAtomicComponent
{
    Atom Parent{ get; }
}
```

These are just presented as ideas, as your question is a bit vague, but hopefully gives you something to go on.

Chemical reactions, have a `takes a` relationship with an `Atom`. From my basic understanding by [reading the wikipedia article on Chemical reactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_reaction) there are a few basic types, the simplest being a Synthesis. This appears to take 2 Atoms and returns a single new one. This you could model again using an interface:

```
public interface ISynthesisReaction
{
   Atom Synthesise(Atom left, Atom right);
}
```

And then you write one or more implementations of that interface. Another might be decomposition which takes a single Atom and can return multiple ones:

```
public interface IDecompositionReaction
{
   Atom [] Decompose(Atom atom);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created Proton, Neutron and Electon as inheriting from Atom. What you're saying here is that the fundamental unit is the Atom, and that protons, neutrons and electrons are special kinds of atom. This clearly isn't the case. Protons, neutrons and electrons are the fundamental units, since you don't specify anything smaller, and an atom contains a number of protons, neutrons and electrons.

Therefore, I'd start by creating an Atom class that has properties describing the number of protons, neutrons and electrons it has. You could make proton, neutron and electron classes and have the atom containing an array of protons, electrons and neutrons, but I'm not sure this would be useful. Certainly you can treat each proton as indistinguishable from any other proton, and likewise for neutrons, but you may wish to be more clever with the electrons. Electrons may be indistinguishable, but the energy levels aren't so if you're going to be going into ionisation you may not want to simply have an integer representing electron number and if you are you may want to consider a structure of energy levels which can be populated or not- depends on what this is for.

You have a string describing what kind of element this is- "Metal". If you're going to be setting some rules, like a metal can react with a non-metal, you're better off defining an enumeration of the different element types. This way you're comparing integers rather than strings, which is more efficient, and there's less scope for typing something wrong and ending up with new type of element that's not recognised by your "reaction" code.

Also, you appear to have made your neutrons *inside* the electron class. This means that a neutron can only exist as part of an electron. And your TestClass is within the neutron again. You need to think about the logical relationships between the different classes, and in a system like this it's unlikely you'll need to define classes within classes- have them as distinct objects and have fields of the classes which are of the appropriate type. So your atom class could, perhaps, start like this:

```
public class Atom
{
    public int number = 11;
    public Electron[] electrons;
    public Proton[] protons;
    public Neutron[] neutrons;
    public string name="Sodium";
    public ElementTypeEnum elementType;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I would actually go a step further and instead of a `number` field, change it to a property and return the length of the `protons` array.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there's no explicit question, I'm going to assume you want a critique.

Inheritance should only be used when entities have an 'IS A' relationship.  E.g. If you can state that 'An Electron is an atom' then you should consider inheriting electron from atom.  As an electron is NOT an atom, it suggests that your inheritance is wrong.  Instead you would state that 'An atom HAS An electron'; a 'HAS A' relationship suggests aggregation, so giving perhaps:

```
    class Atom
    {
        public Electron {get;set;}

        ...
    }
```

(more accurately for the real world, I expect an atom to have a list of 1 or more electrons.)

You appear to be hard-coding the type of the atom into the class (Sodium).  Ideally you would create a base class with holders for the atom type, and have derived classes for specific atom types. E.g.

```
public class Atom
{
    public string Name {get; protected set;}
    public string Type {get; protected set;}
}

public class SodiumAtom : Atom
{
    public SodiumAtom()
    {
        Name = "Sodium";
        Type = "Metal";
    }

}
```

This would allow you to create a specific type of atom, but then reat it like a generic atom:

```
    Atom a = new SodiumAtom();
    a.GetInfo();
```

All your classes have a 'GetInfo' method.  This is a 'cross-cutting' function in that you might want a lot of your classes to have this, regardless of whether they have the same base class.  I would suggest using an interface:

```
public Interface IDisplayInfo
{
    void GetInfo();
}

public class Atom : IDisplayInfo
{
    public void GetInfo()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Electron : IDisplayInfo
{
    public void GetInfo()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```